# Delete Value with Relational Table Trigger vs

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

How do you delete values with a relational database for connected tables.

Example of Movie Database:
Movie Table -> Movie_has_Genre Table -> Genre Table

If I delete a Movie I would want to delete all the rows of Movie_has_Genre table where the foreign key is the same as the id from the movie table.

Should I be using a Trigger on the Movie table (on delete... do a delete on the relational table) or is there some other built in function to handle this?

I just vaguely recall there was another way to do this but cannot remember what it was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the cascade delete statement. It's syntax looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T2
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_T1_T2_Cascade
   FOREIGN KEY (keyId) REFERENCES dbo.T1(keyId) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

The complete syntax is: [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: on delete cascade can sometimes lead to accidental deletes. I like to execute two queries - first to delete (preferably inactivate) data from child table and then delete (or inactivate) data from parent table.

Comment: Feel free to use my recommendation in your answer. You came up with a concise and to-the-point answer already.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in SQL Server to do this automatically via CASCADE settings as already shown.

This is a really handy option but make sure you don’t apply it to all of your tables that have foreign key references as it might cause unexpected loss of data. Make sure to thoroughly analyze weather this won’t cause any damage.

Another option is to use multiple delete statements starting from the tables that are referenced first.